# Archive not shown in Mail.app on Yosemite

Tags: macos, icloud, mail.app, email, archive

I'm not sure what happened, but I don't see Archive mailbox in Mail.app.

[image]

Compared to iCloud.com, there is a Archive directory.

[image]

Wha might be wrong? How can I bring back the Archive box in Mail.app?
I use Mac OS X 10.10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what happened, but the box comes and goes.
I set the Archive box in the favorite toolbar so that I can bring it up when it's not showing itself.

[image]

[image]